# microsecond timer in windows

Tags: c++, timer, callback, c++builder

I'm using C ++ Builder to develop a windows application, and I need to call a function periodically with the time interval given in microseconds. The TTimer class of C ++ Builder only allows me to set this interval in milliseconds. Also I tried to use the Waitable timers of Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-a-waitable-timer-with-an-asynchronous-procedure-call), but also the time can only be adjusted in milliseconds. Is there a way to implement similar functionality in microseconds?

Comment: Microsecond timing on a non-realtime OS is a tough ask. Unless you are willing to throw a ton of cycles away on a busy loop, you might as well just use `max(1, frequency/1000)` in miliseconds, since your precision is probably going to be within that range at best when relying on the OS scheduler.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use the `std::chrono` libraries? Since C++11 that's really the way to go when dealing with time.

Comment: Chrono ultimately calls through to the Windows APIs and Windows just is not built for precise timing.

Comment: Yes, but Windows does have a high performance timer via `QueryPerformance(Counter|Frequency)()` that the `<chrono>` library is likely to use in its implementation on Windows.

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place?  the answer impacts the solution ... for example you can do a dummy thread that is polling the `QueryPerformanceCounter`  and calls/executes your desired code in `[us]` granularity but that would be 100% of single CPU core load and need to adjust affinity and priority to limit OS scheduling interventions ... still you need to take in mind it will be paused often by it. In some cases using FIFOs can eliminate the need for high precision timers ... Sometimes clock tics method is enough ...

Comment: Hello @Spektre, my application is a SCADA system that communicates with a driver I developed using the MODBUS protocol. In this application I needed the information adapted at every 100us, so I need to create a MODBUS query at this interval, so the reason for my query.

Comment: in such case If you have access to the driver you should use FIFOs to communicate ...  that would get rid of the OS scheduler granularity/interruptions problems ... so in most cases you will have feed back in time and in case of task switching the FIFO would just delay the api not crash/miss/loss of data ....

Comment: I attempted to develop a timer whose interval is specified in microseconds.  I used std::chrono::steady_clock in conjunction with std::chrono::microsecond. I found that, if I specified an interval shorter than a millisecond, the timer ticked once per millisecond.  So, consistent with the question description and @user4581301's comment, it appears that std::chrono calls Windows API functions that do not support the specification of intervals shorter than 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be the case that minimal resolution on a timer was +- 10 ms. Even setting a timer on 1ms would not happen after 1ms, but somewhere around 7-10 ms (and occasionally much longer). Finer resolution on a timer, in Windows, would be pointless in this case.  You cannot depend upon a timer for rapid response times, nor can you anticipate when your program may be swapped out of the CPU by the OS.

Comment: This is no longer the case, at least on my PC.  I did tests with a 1 millisecond timer and it's fine.  Also I've developed a music sequencing application that always uses a 1 millisecond ticker as the basis of its timing.  I've not noticed any problems with it.  The 1 millisecond ticker uses JUCE's HighResolutionTimer, which uses std::chrono::steady_clock under the hood.